# SQL - UNION ALL instead of JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help me figure out how to write this script using `UNION ALL`? Currently it is using `JOIN` instead of `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(#vol2016.Destination, #vol2017.Destination) AS [Destination],
    ISNULL(#vol2016.[Volume 2016],0) AS [Volume 2016],
    ISNULL(#vol2017.[Volume 2017],0) AS [Volume 2017],
    ISNULL(#vol2017.[Volume 2017],0) - ISNULL(#vol2016.[Volume 2016],0) AS [Developement]
FROM(
    SELECT
        [year], [Destination], CAST(SUM([Volume]) as INT) as [Volume 2016] 
    FROM [dbo].[dw_lc_full_aggregated_1]
    WHERE [entry_type] = 'Country upload'
    AND [year]='2016'
    GROUP BY [year], [Destination]) #vol2016
FULL JOIN    
(SELECT
     [year], [Destination], CAST(SUM([Volume]) as INT) as [Volume 2017]
 FROM [dbo].[dw_lc_full_aggregated_1]
 WHERE [entry_type] = 'Country upload' AND [year]='2017'
 GROUP BY [year], [Destination]) #vol2017
ON [#vol2016].Destination=[#vol2017].Destination
```

So the output should be in three columns. Destination, Volume 2016, Volume 2017.

Comment: `UNION ALL` will give you more rows, not more columns.  If you want to have more columns, then JOIN is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT [year]
     , [Destination]
     , CAST(SUM([Volume]) as INT) AS [Volume]
  FROM
    (
        SELECT [year]
             , [Destination]
             , [Volume]
          FROM [dbo].[dw_lc_full_aggregated_1]
         WHERE [entry_type] = 'Country upload' AND [year]='2016'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  [year]
              , [Destination]
              , [Volume]
          FROM  [dbo].[dw_lc_full_aggregated_1]
         WHERE  [entry_type] = 'Country upload' AND [year]='2017'
    ) AS T
GROUP BY [year],[Destination]
```

Comment: Thank you. Still no success.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: `SELECT foo FROM (<query1> UNION ALL <query2>) AS combined GROUP BY stuff`

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** actually make life a lot more simple for yourself with conditional aggregation *(A `CASE` statement inside the `SUM()`)*

```
SELECT
    [Destination],
    [Volume_2016],
    [Volume_2017],
    [Volume_2017] - [Volume_2016]   AS [Development]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Destination],
        CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [year] = '2016' THEN [Volume] END) as INT) [Volume_2016],
        CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [year] = '2017' THEN [Volume] END) as INT) [Volume_2017]
    FROM
        [dbo].[dw_lc_full_aggregated_1]
    WHERE
            [entry_type] =  'Country upload'
        AND [year]       IN ('2016', '2017')
    GROUP BY
        [Destination]
)
    AS pivoted_agreggate
```

***EDIT:*** `[Year]` removed from `GROUP BY` *(copy and paste error)*